# How do you make Visual Studio/CodeMaid insert newlines before and after #region and #endregion?

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, codemaid

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (CodeMaid), I want Visual Studio to add newlines before and after `#region` and `#endregion` in following languages: `C#, CSS, JS`

How I can make it happen?

For ex:

```
#region

Codes

#endregion
```

BTW, now Visual Studio remove any inserted `enter` on `#region`s.

Answer (score 1):

By default, it's enabled if not you can make sure it's green
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, CodeMaid will insert blank line padding before/after `#region` and `#endregion` statements.  There is additional logic that will prevent that from happening based on the surrounding context (e.g. if it's the first item inside a set of braces).

Note:  This only applies to C#.  I'm not sure what you mean by CSS and JS as neither of those languages support `#pragma` statements to my knowledge.